# Buld DLL with Gradle cpp plugin

Tags: c++, gradle, dll

Have a module:

```
mod-native
------  build
------  sources
------------    myDll
----------------------- cpp
------------------------------  dllmain.cpp
------------------------------  MakeString.cpp
------------------------------  stdafx.cpp
------------------------------  MyDll.cpp
----------------------- headers
------------------------------  base64.h
------------------------------  tmain.h
------  build.gradle
```

So, my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'

model{
    toolChains{
        vs(VisualCpp){
            installDir "C:\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0"
            windowsSdkDir "C:\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0"
        }
    }
    // target binary for win32
    platforms{
        win32{
            architecture "i386"
            operatingSystem "windows"
        }
    }
    components {
            toCms(NativeLibrarySpec){
                sources{
                    cpp{
                        source.srcDir "sources/myDll/cpp"
                        exportedHeaders.srcDir "sources/myDll/headers"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I want to gett MyDll.dll file, but it seems gradle tries to build *.lib file instead of *.dll. How can I build MyDll.dll ?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When not specified, gradle will build both *.lib and *.dll, it depends on which task you execute.

If you execute task *toCmsDebug**Shared**Library* it should work

Note: you should use gradle default layout (so you will not have to set manually *srcDir*) :

```
src/
----*component name*/
---------cpp/
---------headers/
```

Note 2:
When you want to compile a *.exe be sure you run task beginning with "install" (eg: *installMyCmsDebugExecutable*) it makes a big difference because Visual Studio will run this one.

You can check which task is executed for the build in the *.vcxproj, xml tag is `<NMakeBuildCommandLine>`